# What is the recommended way to pretty print HTML or code excerpts in AngularDart

Tags: dart, pretty-print, angular-dart

What is the recommended way to pretty print HTML or code excerpts in AngularDart? Is there a package to help achieve this (have found none), or do developers simply use "external" packages like [google-code-prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)?

Comment: What do you mean with 'pretty print'? Only syntax highlighting or really fix formatting (like indentation) issues?

Comment: Rainbows is what AngularUI uses for its site: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0):

I use this http://craig.is/making/rainbows/
You add a javascript tag and some classes to your tags containing your code - that's it.

If you want to include HTML including Angular markup you can use `ng-non-bindable` to prevent Angular processing tags and attributes it may have selectors for.